# до установки Flutter SDK нужно устанавливать Dart SDK

Tags: flutter, dart

До установки **Flutter SDK** нужно устанавливать **Dart SDK** или язык Dart там уже находится автоматически? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Dart SDK has the libraries and command-line tools that you need to
>   develop Dart web, command-line, and server apps. If you’re developing
>   only mobile apps, then you don’t need the Dart SDK; just install
>   Flutter.

[Как говорит источник](https://dart.dev/get-dart): Нет, для **Flutter SDK** устанавливать отдельно **Dart** не нужно. Он уже идет в комплекте *(Урезанная версия)*.

[Инструкция по установке **Flutter SDK**.](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install)

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: @Anton всегда пожалуйста, если будут вопросы спрашивайте!